# Why is my Flat-Panel Dimmable LED tripping the breaker?

Tags: electrical, lighting, circuit-breaker, led

I added a dedicated 15 amp breaker to our box specifically to power 2 flat-panel, dimmable, LED fixtures ( Metalux / Eaton - Model: ELL-CCD-UNV-A-038-0900-SQR-A-A ).

I've tried standard, single-pole switches between the box and the fixture - in one trial, the switch shorted and the fixture remained on. In another trial ( duplicate switch ) the circuit breaker popped and shorted out.

I've tried different model manufacturers of 15 amp circuit breakers - same issues.
Please.

What combination of circuit breaker and switch to I need to use to make this arrangement work ?

Comment: A picture of the wiring at the switch would help get answers. I'm worried that you are just randomly trying different wire combinations, which is dangerous.

Comment: Electric panels are made to only take certain breakers.  The types and makes of breakers that will fit and work in your panel should be listed on a label on the panel.  Using other breakers can be bad.  With the information you have provided so far, the suggestion of having an electrician in to check out your work is highly recommended for your safety.

Comment: My approach would be to triage the lamp and the wiring.  Put a plug on the lamp and plug it into a known good outlet.  Does it blow that breaker?   Put wire nuts on the end of the circuit feeding the lamp and turn on the breaker.  Does it blow?  Put a simple pigtail lamp on it ... does it blow?   If it's the cabling, disconnect it at the switch or try connecting the lamp directly to the switch  .. This would help prove it's the cabling between switch and ceiling box.  Proceed in that manner .. divide and conquer.

Comment: Are you sure you're wiring it correctly?  It's difficult for us to know the assumptions you have about what is correct.  LED fixtures aren't going to cause a breaker-tripping short.   Does the breaker have a "TEST" button?  Those are unforgiving to other wiring errors.  I agree with temporarily wiring the fixture to a plug to test the fixture itself.